# Can anyone ID this fossilized bone

Tags: species-identification, vertebra

Is this a fossilized backbone? If so then from what?
This "bone" is approximately four inches (10 cm) wide by two inches (5 cm) deep and two inches (5 cm) tall. The texture is rock-like. If it resembles any bone familiar to anyone let me know or take a guess and I'll look into it. I found it in North central Texas in the ground by a massive fruitless mulberry tree on the top of a hill. It weighs about what a 2x2x4 inch chunk of average run of the mill stone would weigh.

[image: fossilized vertebra?]

[image: fossilized vertebra?]

[image: fossilized vertebra?]

[image: fossilized vertebra?]

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE. As written, this post -- in my opinion -- is unanswerable and will be closed. Please review the [guidelines for asking](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) [tag:species-identification] questions. You need to update your post with size(s), location, circumstances, etc. Given the unclear nature of your specimen, photographs from multiple angles with better lighting will be necessary. Describing the weight and texture might also be relevant. Please add as much detail as you can. Thanks

Comment: Please add a more specific location than "North America" Also note that "by a tree" is not helpful — please add environmental and geological information to the best of your ability. ——— In addition, in the future please proofread and edit your posts and make sure all the pictures are visible (you had inserted links into each other breaking most of them). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Please be very specific about the location you found it. North America is too coarse of a location -- ideally, we should know the exact location (or as close to it as possible). You should at least include the city. Knowing the ecology, natural history, and human history of the site you found it will also be relevant. If you know any of this please share. If not, then a specific location (and photo) would be best. Also, please provide more info about how you found it: What type of tree? on what type of property? How far down in the ground? Soil type? Etc...

Comment: It looks like just a rock, not fossilized bone.

Comment: You can put this on the earth stack to be answered. I suggest adding pictures of all sides of the object not just multiple pictures of the same side from different angles, specifically and broken areas are helpful. locality will also be helpful, right now it just looks like a rock.